# Absolute signs in solving ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$\frac{1}{y} \frac{\text{d}y}{\text{d}x} = \frac{1}{x}$$

The way I solve this:

for all $x$ in $(-\infty,0)$

$\ln |y| = \ln |x| + A$  where $A$ is a real constant (since we know antiderivatives are separated by a constant)

$|y| = B|x|$ where $B$ is a positive constant equals $\exp(A)$

$y= Bx$ or $-Bx$

It seems to me $y =Cx$ where $C$ is a real non-zero constant that equals either $B$ or $-B$.

Since it seems like if $y$ is equal to $+$ or $-Bx$ for the entire interval $(-\infty,0)$, then it must be only $+Bx$ or $-Bx$ i.e. $Cx$ for some subinterval. If it is $+Bx$, then for values outside and near this interval, they must also be $+Bx$ since we know $y$ is continuous and $x$ is not zero. Vice versa.

But I don't know how to prove this. How to prove $y = Cx$ for $(-\infty, 0)$?

If that is the case, then I can write the general form of the differential equation picewisely as $y=C_1x$ for $(-\infty,0)$, $C_2x$ for $(0,\infty)$, where $C_1$ and $C_2$ are non-zero reals.

Comment: If y=1 when x=1, then we know B = 1 and y = + or -  x for x in (0,infinity). We also know y=x at x=1. By intuition, it then seems obvious that y=x for (0,inifinity), but how to prove this?

Comment: consider Intermediate Value Theorem

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Consider the DE in its explicit normal form $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y}{x}$. The difference is that the equation is now defined for $y=0$, inside the quadrants the solutions remain the same.

As an ODE, this equation is singular or not defined on the line $x=0$. Thus the solutions on $(-\infty,0)$ and $(0,+\infty)$ are separate, with separate integration constants. For the solution as ODE one need not care much of how they connect at $x=0$.

$y=0$ is a solution of the explicit ODE, or outside the domain for the original equation. Thus no other solution can change its sign, trivially by not being able to leave its quadrant, or by the uniqueness property of the Picard-Lindelöf (-Cauchy-Lipschitz) theorem on existence and uniqueness. As the sign is fixed, it is determined by the initial condition, one could write
$$
\frac{x}{x_0}=\frac{y}{y_0}.
$$

Comment: If you put the DE in normal form $y'=y/x$, as one usually does for solving DE.

Comment: This does not properly address the question.

Comment: @Angel: In what way? The question was asking why the constant factor in the solution has a constant sign, the answer is that no sign change takes place in any component, thus the signed constant is completely determined by the initial condition.

Comment: I assume you use “change of sign” to mean the coefficient of y is constant for all negative x (another constant for all positive x) (what I was originally asking for a proof about). I think you can just see no solution y can “changes its sign” by simply noting 1/y and y is continuous. There is no need for all of that, right? Sorry if I interpret it wrong, what you did seem to only prove y is never zero using the uniqueness property, rather than by simply noting 1/y. Also you did not explain explicitly how y not equal to zero means it cannot “change sign”.

Comment: I green ticked this question because when I read this, I considered y, for negative x, changes its sign only if it is zero for some x, leading to a contradiction, and therefore the coefficient of y is constant for all negative x.

Answer (score 0):

The first point of confusion here is that you antidifferentiatied $$\frac{y'}{y}=\frac1{x}$$ to $$\ln(|y|)=\ln(|x|)+A,$$ but this is not entirely correct. The antiderivatives of $\frac1{t}$ are given by the piecewise, $$\ln(-t)+A;\,\forall{t\lt0}$$ $$\ln(t)+A;\,\forall{t\gt0}.$$ Taking this into account, you should have $$\ln(-y)=\ln(-x)+A$$ or $$\ln(y)=\ln(-x)+B.$$ This translates to $$y(x)=\exp(A)x$$ or $$y(x)=-\exp(B)x.$$

The second point of is in interpreting the "or." The two solutions we have here are that $y(x)=c_0x$ with $c_0\gt0,$ or that $y(x)=c_1x$ with $c_1\lt0.$ You could not have both happening simultaneously in all of $(-\infty,0).$ Your question is, how do you prove it? Well, notice that the equation must be satisfied everywhere. But it cannot be satisfied if there are jump discontinities, which occur if you have a constant of one kind in one subinterval, and a constant of some other kind everywhere else. You can show that if $$f(x)=\begin{cases}Ax&x\leq{C}\\Bx&x\gt{C}\end{cases},$$ then $f$ is not even differentiable at $C$ unless $A=B.$ You can prove it just using the definition of the derivative. The method for solving the equation, when done properly, already implies this, though, so in practice, you would not need to prove it.

Comment: It’s good that you pointed out my first confusion about 1/x. For the proof of f(x) given, you just proved it cannot changes constants for two INTERVALS which seem to have been mentioned by me in the post. You seem to be assuming y have two coefficients for all negative x if and only if it does so for two sub-intervals. I don’t see how is that true. Could you expand on that?

Comment: I think a simpler and better way is to make use of the Intermediate Value Theorem from the start. Suppose y is positive for one negative x and sometimes negative for another negative x, then y is zero for some x between which is a contradiction. Therefore y is either positive for all negative x  or negative for all negative x. And then an anti-derivative of LHS for all negative x would be ln(y), or ln(-y).

Comment: ln(−)=ln(−)+
ln
⁡
(
−
y
)
=
ln
⁡
(
−
x
)
+
A
or
ln()=ln(−)+.

Comment: I don’t see how the above statement is arrived at. To find an anti-derivative of LHS for negative x, one requires substitution rule. Since y is sometimes positive and sometimes negative and never zero, then y is not continuous and substitution cannot be used. I don’t know how you did that. But I think it is unnecessary here as I already figured out a simple way as commented above.

Comment: I will green tick if you could clarify my two doubts above, as, again, the first point is very useful.

Comment: @TFR *I don’t see how the above statement is arrived at. To find an anti-derivative of LHS for negative x, one requires substitution rule. Since y is sometimes positive and sometimes negative and never zero, then y is not continuous and substitution cannot be used. I don’t know how you did that.* $y$ is not sometimes positive and sometimes negative. It is **either** positive **or else** negative. The "or" between equations here represents different families of solutions. There is one family of solutions where $y$ is always positive on $(-\infty,0),$...

Comment: @TFR And another family of solutions where $y$ is always negative on $(-\infty,0).$ Of course, both families can be consolidated into a single family of solutions: the family where $y$ is nonzero. But this consolidation is done after you solve the equations and work on the two previous families separately, at least if you are using the solution method that I used. I realized my wording was not the best for explaining that in my answer, though I am not sure how I could word it better without making it unnecessarily long.

Comment: @TFR *You seem to be assuming y have two coefficients for all negative x if and only if it does so for two sub-intervals. I don’t see how is that true.* That is not what I intended to communicate. Essentially I am doing a proof by contradiction here. What I am saying is, suppose that there is some open interval $(a,b)$ in $(-\infty,0)$ where $y\lt0,$ and $(-\infty,a)\cup(b,0)$ where $y\gt0.$ Then $y$ is not differentiable at $a$ and $b,$ which contradicts the fact that $y$ satisfies the differential equation everywhere in $(-\infty,0).$

Comment: @TFR And on that note, I am not convinced that using the intermediate value theorem is simpler than the proof by contradiction I intended.

Comment: What I think you are doing: I think you only proved it is false that y can be negative for one interval and positive for values outside and near that interval. I think your proof is based on the assumption that, if y is positive for some values x, and negative else, then either there exists an x at which y is positive, and near which negative; or, there exists an interval of x in which y is positive, and near which negative. Your proof by contradiction proved it is impossible for the second case, and the first case is so obvious that I think you just ignored implicitly.

Comment: But do you think this assumption is true? It makes SOME sense intuitively.

Comment: I know y is either positive for all negative x, or negative for all negative x. However, as you just mentioned, that consolidation is done at the end, (although using IVT one can do it at the beginning), at the beginning, you have no idea what y is, and how can you just anti-differentiate using substitution? My previous wording was not clear, but what I was saying is you have to assume y might be sometimes positive and sometimes negative, and never zero, and substitution method doesn’t work for that case.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133089/discussion-between-angel-and-tfr).